# Best way to create invoices tables SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have these tables:

```
* gasm_clients
id_client INT NOT NULL,
name_client VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
cellphone_client VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL

* gasm_invoices
id_invoice INT NOT NULL,
(id_client || client_name) --> I'm not sure of these two columns which use
invoice_total DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL
....
```

Must clarify that clients have to be registered first in another form, but to make a fast invoice, I only need the client's name without registering it in the clients table.

I want to allow to the user search all registered clients or single write the client name.

```
EX: 
1. Choose Client
2. Write name
```

But I don't know what is the best way to do this on SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to minimize duplication and maintain data integrity hd1's way is correct.

There should be a primary key - foreign key relationship between the `GASM_CLIENTS` and `GASM_INVOICES` tables. You can specify this relationship while creating `GASM_INVOICES` table in your respective DBMS. Specifying this relationship will ensure that the column `GASM_INVOICES.id_client` contains a reference to a valid row in the `GASM_CLIENTS` table.

Next, you do not have to register your customer every time. This is simple to solve. Keep the `id_client` an auto-generated integer primary key, `name_client` as `not null` and remove the `not null` constraint on `cellphone_client` column. There is no need of this constraint on this column. It will only increase data overhead and confusion.

Also, it is a bad idea to reference one table from the other using a column other than primary key (ID) unless absolutely required.

Now, with this schema, you can design a front-end logic in which when the operator enters a client's name, the software can search it in the `gasm_clients` table and show the operator the search results to choose from. Else, the operator may choose to add this new name a s a new client which will be added into the database.

The actual `INSERT INTO` queries will be too many to write here in this answer. Just make the changes I have mentioned here, read a few excellent books like Korth's and other on database design and you will get the idea.

I hope my answer is helpful enough.

Comment: Sincerely your response to me helped tremendously, now I understand better how to do to solve this doubt confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You want to minimise data duplication when architecting a database. The first option (id_client) would be what I'd use.

Comment: Yea me too, But if I wish that the user could write the name of the client directly, without need to register the client? Where I store the name of the client ? i need to add another field in the table of invoices establishing in NULL? I do not like the idea of ​​having many times the field name_client